# How to print string if variable is empty

Tags: twig

I have the following HTML/TWIG:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
```

Now I'd like to use `value="Username"` if `last_username` is empty. But I also don't want to make an if for this. So, could I do something like:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username or 'Username'}}" />
```

I know that I could set a default value on the logic side of my application - not sure what would be better practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `default` filter

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username | default('Username') }}" />
```